# Having some troubles with MetadataType, Annotations and EF

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use data annotations to validate my Entity Framework models using partial classes.

I was told in this [article (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx), that the partial class should be in the same namespace as the data model. My data model is located in EntityFrameworkDataProvider, so my partial class which is located in MyApp.Backend.Models looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EntityFrameworkDataProvider
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ItemMetaData))]
    public partial class Item { }

    public class ItemMetaData
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object CreateDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I validate the model in my controller class like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit(Item item)
{
    if (!TryUpdateModel(item))
    {
        return View(item);
    }

    return View("Details", item);
}
```

It compiles without errors. However, when trying to edit an item this error is what I get:

**Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'EntityFrameworkDataProvider.Item' exists in both 'long-path.DLL' and 'long-path.DLL'**

I guess the Item class is being compiled twice or something. How should this error be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller action is wrong. You should never use action parameters and `TryUpdateModel` on the same type because it will insert the error messages twice in the model state. Your action should look like this instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit(Item item)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(item);
    }
    return View("Details", item);
}
```

As far as the compiler error message you are getting you haven't provided enough information so that I can help you. Make sure that this Item class is not defined in different locations and that it is indeed `partial` in every single `.cs` file you encounter it. I suspect that somewhere you have an `Item` class defined which is not partial. What you should be aware of as well is that if this Item class is defined in a separate assembly, even if it is marked with partial, once compiled, the notion of partial no longer exists. Partial classes work only within the same assembly.

Comment: sure, that might be correct but it doesn't change the fact that the two assemblies "collides". +1 for the tip, though.

Comment: Is by any chance this `Item` class defined in a separate assembly and by separate I mean different than the assembly that contains the code you have posted?

Comment: It's 2 projects... EntityFrameworkDataProvider.Item and MyApp.Backend.Models (asp.net mvc app). Not sure if separate project == separate assembly?

Comment: Yes it's separate assembly. This explains the error message. You can have partial classes only within the same project. Once compiled they cease to be partial. The notion of a partial class doesn't exist in a compiled assembly. It is there only to allow you to split the definition of a class in multiple source files. So the only way for this to work is to put this partial Item class definition into the other project.

Comment: Okay, but isn't there a workaround for this? I can't have the model in the web project... it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: No, the model should be in the separate project. In your web project you only might need view models. So put all your models into this separate project, it will also contain the validation attributes.